# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem in my jquery code . Can any one help me regarding this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target

```
$(function() {
  $('#Events').on("slides", function({
    generateNextPrev: true, 
    play: 5000,
    pause: 2500,
    hoverPause: true,
    preload: true,
    preloadImage: '/images/loading.gif'
  });

  // $('#slides_container').css("display", "inline");
  );
});
```

This error is coming in this line `generateNextPrev: true,`. Kindly guide me, what's the issue.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. You cannot define an object in the arguments of a function. Exactly what are you expecting this code to do?

Comment: Also note that you have an extra `)` in there, but I assume this is a typo when writing the question

Comment: @Rory - please clarify: _You cannot define an object in the arguments of a function_

Comment: See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions), or @Ian's answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56398576/519413.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply I solved the issue, the issue came because of javascript version.

Answer (score 4):

This is invalid syntax - take a look at the function declaration on line 1 vs line 2. I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but you must have a function body. You have this: `.on("slides", function({...});` which has an unclosed parenthesis and no function body. `.on("slides", function(parameters) {/*do stuff here*/});` is the syntax you need; I'm not really sure where the object is intended to go.